# Complex Analysis, Basel Problem and $ \int^1_0 -\frac{\log(1-t)}{t}~\mathrm{d}t$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, residue-calculus

Knowing that
$\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$, one can prove that
$$
I := \int^1_0 -\frac{\log(1-t)}{t}~\mathrm{d}t = \frac{\pi^2}{6}.
$$

With that said, I am fairly new to complex analysis. I am wondering, if one could also compute $I$ using e.g. the Residue Theorem (with which I am probably not yet "familiar enough" to solve this). Is this possible?

If the residue method is not possible, is there any method to compute the integral $I$ without resorting to the fact $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$?

Comment: To start, I would make the change of variables $t = 1 - e^{-s}$ to have a meromorphic function under the integral.

Comment: Okay, sounds legit. But how to proceed?